# How to get the posts counts and comments counts from a Facebook page without Authentication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, web-scraping

I want to get the number of comments and posts on a facebook fan page by a cron job. Are there any possible ways to do this other than scraping the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an app and be authorised to do that. You aren't allowed to scrape facebook pages (see https://www.facebook.com/terms.php point 3)

Comment: My answer still applies. I read the question to mean that currently they are using scraping, but want to use another method. I may be wrong but it doesn't hurt to add the extra info.

Comment: Thanks Abby for that..We are not making a Facebook App but want to do some kind of tracking for some brands. A Task should trigger daily and check for new posts and comments. We are just interested in the Numbers though

Comment: You will need to use an app to get the page data without scraping. You can't get it without authorisation, and you cant get authorisation without an app. You know most of the comment counts are available in insights already?

Comment: Advice does! And so does answer. Sorry don't know what I was thinking. @user996048 Building app is the only way and its pretty easy too. Making an app doesn't mean you have to be live on Facebook. Just a mean to make API calls which Facebook can keep track of.